# Resize phonegap image

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to resize my image that I have taken using phonegap camera plugin to 960x720:

The code I am using is below

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    targetWidth : 960,
    targetHeight : 720,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the code indicated that the you are already taking  960X720.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the destinationType to `FILE_URI`as from the Cordova docs:

"Photo resolution on newer devices is quite good. Photos selected from the device's gallery are not downscaled to a lower quality, even if a quality parameter is specified. To avoid common memory problems, set Camera.destinationType to FILE_URI rather than DATA_URL."